# Javascript does not affect navbar in my flask bootstrap website

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I'm making a navbar for my flask website using bootstrap. When i put it in my html it looks like https://gyazo.com/08b1f636caf7342d3657b6f13bfbdadd which i assume is because the js isnt working.
My html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
             <ul class="navbar-nav">
             <li class="nav-item active">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

My flask python code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("base.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

code from tech with tim and bootstrap website.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you have two link tags with two different versions of bootstrap there? Maybe try to remove one of those. Also, if you check network requests on your browser when your website loads, is the GET request to bootstrap.css successful?

Comment: @durzal in your code you have attached 2 different CSS in the head tag and bottom part of code remove bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6 CSS attached  file

Comment: @vremes I removed the  bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6 CSS attached file viking said to remove. But i dont know how to check network requests on the browser. Can you teach me how to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: @vremes edit: i think i know what you're talking about. Whenever i click on the navbar i get the same thing as when i reload the page.  127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2020 19:03:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with this version of bootstrap as it is somewhat old.
so try to use the latest version.

Also, you are using

```
<!doctype html>
```

instead of

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

usually, it doesn't matter but maybe the browser has a problem with it

#### Use this code it has the latest version of bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

#### Flask

Maybe flask is caching responses. So use these configurations on the top of your flask app

```
# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

# Ensure responses aren't cached
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response
```